# How to write a newline in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I tried to do `\n`, but it did not work.

What string may I write in org-mode to create a new line?

For example, I wrote the following lines in literate programming:

```
#+begin_src clojure
     "test/ntest"
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: test/ntest
```

but the result is not doing new line.

Comment: If you mean export, you can leave a blank line in org file.

Comment: "... it did not work": that is a very common description of a problem and it is almost always completely useless. Say exactly what you want to accomplish, what you tried, what the result was. As you can see from the previous comment, it is not clear what you meant: are you talking about a newline in the Org mode buffer in Emacs? If so, just RET should work fine - Org mode files are text files. Are you talking about breaking a line when you export? @TianshuWang's comment may help. But in this case, you should also specify what you export *to*: HTML, PDF, ODT?  Asking a good question ...

Comment: ... takes thought and practice. There are many good guides available on the web - e.g. [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Read one or more before asking your next question: it will help you and it will help the people who are eager to answer your questions.

Comment: I update my question. Sorry for being that imprecise. @NickD

Comment: You have misspelled `\n` using a forward slash, rather than a backslash.  I don't have `clojure` but the equivalent block in `elisp` works fine.

Comment: Works for me in emacs lisp, but not in clojure.

Answer (score 0):

Most people just hit enter, just like in any other buffer. If that doesn’t work for you, then you should include more information about the problem.

Comment: I can't i just want to print a new line with literate programming.

Comment: If you are writing a program in a source block then you would use whatever syntax is ordinarily used by that programming language. You should include that information in you question too.